# nestjs ConfigModule.forRoot() asynchronuous

Tags: rest, asynchronous, configuration, nestjs

I want to load config in Nestjs from a configuration server with a REST API to allow for centralized application configuration.  However there is no async version of the ConfigModule.forRoot() function so the configuration returns as `undefined`.

Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 4):

Solved by creating a factory function that returns a Nest ConfigService object

```js
// config-factory.ts
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import axios from 'axios'

export async function getConfigService() {
  const host = ...
  const port = ...
  const configUrl = `http://${host}:${port}/config`
  const postData = ...
  const response = await axios.post<Record<string, any> | undefined>(configUrl, postData)

  return new ConfigService(response.data)
}
```

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useFactory: getConfigService,
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I suspect that both host and port are hardcoded in this answer!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files), you can inject a custom configuration file via the load parameter. Ordinarily, you would pass a synchronous factory function that returns a pre-generated object with the Record<string, any> format, but you can also pass an async factory function here, and your config will be loaded from the server before the application bootstrap without the need to inject the ConfigService as a Custom Provider (if you do that, the ConfigModule is not properly being registered in the App, you can't access it in the main.ts, and you can't use the ConfigModule options).

Example:

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { load } from './loadConfig';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [async () => load({})],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**loadConfig.ts**

```
import { SSM } from 'aws-sdk';

export const load = async (options: any): Promise<any> => {
  const test = new SSM({ region: 'eu-north-1' });

  const parameters = await test
    .getParametersByPath({
      Path: '/path/to/ssm/route/',
      Recursive: true,
    })
    .promise();

  return parameters
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this works?  This is exactly what I tried and nestjs does not seem to wait for the load factory promise to resolve before loading other modules.  In my case, these other modules require the ConfigService to be injected but its config is not done loading so all the values are undefined.

Comment: Yes, it worked properly in my case, and according to the [github repo](https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/master/lib/interfaces/config-factory.interface.ts) the config factory, which is being passed on to the load parameter, can accept a promise, the caveat is that the syntax is somewhat unexpected, but try to play around with the load _function_ and make sure that it is passed to the load _option_ of the config module as  `load: [async () => load({})]`.

My parameters were properly downloaded from the SSM (for example, my TypeORM creds), and TypeORM module loaded correctly.

Comment: It does not work for me in the latest `nest/config`.  It looked like it was working because my properties were still specified in a local `.env`.  But after setting `ignoreEnvVars: true, ingoreEnvFile: true` I can confirm it does not work.  All execution proceeds until the async ssm call and then other modules get loaded.  In my case, the other modules need config to be ready but it is not actually ready.  I think it has something to do with nest dynamically loading several `ConfigModules` in this case. Essentially an empty `ConfigModule` is ready but my dynamically loaded one is not.

Comment: @greenreign, I've just tested it with the 1.2.0 config. IgnoreEnv options do not affect the issue based on the source code. Here is my [load util](https://github.com/macc4/nestjs-clinic/blob/main/apps/common-copy/src/config/loadConfig.ts), and an example of usage is [here](https://github.com/macc4/nestjs-clinic/blob/main/apps/profile/src/modules/shared/shared.module.ts). My database creds are [commented out](https://github.com/macc4/nestjs-clinic/blob/main/apps/profile/src/config/config.base.yaml), but TypeORM loads successfully because its creds are pulled from SSM (SSM creds are local).

Comment: I'd encountered the same issue, the double async function won't help, the config is not done loading and all configs from async calling is undefined.

Comment: I solved it by refactoring the services using `ConfigService` into a new module from the AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

[nest-typed-config](https://github.com/Nikaple/nest-typed-config#using-remote-loader) supports this. It also provides config validation and strong types:

```
TypedConfigModule.forRootAsync({
  schema: RootConfig,
  load: remoteLoader('http://localhost:8080', {
    /* options */
  }),
});
```