# how to access .env variables for Neo4j in Nestjs v8 app.module

Tags: node.js, neo4j, nestjs

I have what appears to be a common problem without a common solution. I am trying to access my .env data from my Nestjs app.module while importing Neo4jModule. If I use hardcoded values everything works fine but neither process.env or configService seems to get the values. I have seem many examples of this problem but apparently the answer is quite elusive. I have tried the following variations of answers but none works. I do understand that we are a bit early in the initialization process but I can't figure out how to delay the request until the initialization is complete.

```
---->app.module
........
 import configuration from './config/configuration';
 import { Neo4jConfig, Neo4jModule } from 'nest-neo4j'
 import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


 @Module({
     imports: [DbServerModule,
               ConfigModule.forRoot({
                 load: [configuration],
                 isGlobal: true
               }),
               Neo4jModule.forRootAsync({
                 imports: [ConfigModule],
                 useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                   scheme: 'bolt',                                    
                   host: configService.get('NEO4J_HOST'),            
                   port: configService.get('NEO4J_PORT'),               
                   username: configService.get('NEO4J_USERNAME'),    
                   password: configService.get('NEO4J_PASSWORD'),               
              }),
    
             inject: [ConfigService],
           }),
          ],
     ........

OR
@Module({
  imports: [DbServerModule,
            ConfigModule.forRoot({
              load: [configuration],
              isGlobal: true
            }),
            Neo4jModule.forRoot({
                scheme: 'bolt',                                   // 
                process.env.NEO4J_SCHEME, 
                host: process.env.NEO4J_HOST, 
                port: process.env.NEO4J_PORT,  
                username: process.env.NEO4J_USERNAME, 
                password: process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD            
              }),

          ],
```

EDIT........
The code below shows we have access to the .env variables within the useFactory {} block...the console.log logs the correct .env value, but still Neo4j connection fails because of the properties:

```
Neo4jModule.forRootAsync({
     inject: [ConfigService],
     useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {         
     console.log(`USERNAME...
                .${configService.get('NEO4J_USERNAME')}`);
     return ({
              scheme: 'bolt',                                    
              host: configService.get('NEO4J_HOST'),            
              port: configService.get('NEO4J_PORT'),               
              username: configService.get('NEO4J_USERNAME'),    
              password: configService.get('NEO4J_PASSWORD'),               
            });
          },
```

My production deployment will be using Rancher to assign the env variables and so I will be using a custom config file.. configuration.ts which I load in ConfigModule.forRoot. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

I need to give a shout-out to @adamCowley for his work on the nest-neo4j wrapper. It has removed a lot of the complexities in integrating Nestjs with Neo4j...Thanks

EDIT: per request:
-config/configuration.ts

```
  .....
  NEO4J_SCHEME: process.env.NEO4J_SCHEME,       
    NEO4J_HOST: process.env.NEO4J_HOST,         
    NEO4J_USERNAME: process.env.NEO4J_USERNAME, 
    NEO4J_PASSWORD: process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD, 
    NEO4J_PORT: process.env.NEO4J_PORT,
   ......
```

.env

```
........
NEO4J_SCHEME='bolt'
NEO4J_HOST='127.0.0.1',       
NEO4J_USERNAME='username'
NEO4J_PASSWORD='password'
NEO4J_PORT=7687
..........
```

Comment: thanks for config files, but a little bit more on `/configuration.ts` may help. for example, what is exported function here, an empty lambda, and do you wrap the result in another object? and why are you just returning exactly same things out. and also can you try to be more clear about your `HOST` variable, where and when you want to set it. I feel it may solve using async-await in your configuration.ts file, but it is now a bit blurred to me after reading your edit/comment.

Comment: meanwhile check if this applies to you problem: [nestjs ConfigModule.forRoot() asynchronuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69771141/nestjs-configmodule-forroot-asynchronuous)

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz  maybe I am not  clear....let my try again. Nestjs uses dotenv to collect the values from .env. We also know that Nestjs then make those available via the configuration.ts file and ConfigService. These seems to be working fine....no problem here. The problem occurs when app.module tries to collect the .env values either from process.env or ConfigService. This is done in Neo4jModule.forRootAsync{.....useFactory: async(.....)}. Where five values should be returned (SCHEME,HOST, USERNAME,PASSWORD and PORT). All can be passed using either process.env or ConfigService except HOST.

Comment: ok, now it gets weirder. I thought you are fetching HOST from somewhere else where some async/await would be fit. now you are saying everything is in the same place and only HOST does not seem to work. have you checked logs for any error messages about formatting issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking [nestjs-neo4j-realworld-example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/nestjs-neo4j-realworld-example/blob/master/src/app.module.ts), your problem might be caused by `useFactory` being `async`.

if `Neo4jModule` fires the `useFactory` method but does not `await` for the return, then you will still see the log in the console, but Neo4j will be called with empty config before that.

try this change

```
from:
useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService){}
----
to:
useFactory: (configService: ConfigService): Neo4jConfig{}
```

if this does not solve your problem, then edit you post and provide a stripped-down version of your `./config/configuration` file, along with your config file, for these 4 variables.

---

EDIT:
Thanks for adding config contents.  I have compared them to my configs. If you copy/paste'd your material, yours is just a typo issue. You have a forgotten trailing comma at the end of the line for the HOST.

Besides the type, `.env` files basically parsed into arrays of two parts before and after `=` exactly as written. since they are first read as strings, there is no need for quotes. also some libraries may skim the second part from quotes but most dont, then safer to omit them in my opinion.

```
NEO4J_SCHEME=bolt
NEO4J_HOST=127.0.0.1
NEO4J_USERNAME=username
NEO4J_PASSWORD=password
NEO4J_PORT=7687
```

PS: From your commentary responses, I deduced everything is in the same place and all except HOST does work, and so this edit should help. If it won't, please edit your post to reflect our discussions in the comments so the next person can see the problem clearer than me and provide help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion....it didn't work however. To be clear only the HOST parameter has to be hardcoded in APP.MODULE for it to work. The other parameters...PORT, USERNAME, SCHEME and PASSWORD are all properly receiving the value from process.env.  so it shouldn't be an async problem.

Comment: can you give a little bit more about them? which ones must be in ".env", which are hardcoded in the source, and which ones should be neither hardcoded nor in ".env" but rather read dynamically. because I am now confused about your goals now.

Comment: @MichaelE, please check the edit to the answer. I hope it fixes the problem. If not, I wish/hope for someone else to provide an answer.

Comment: Eureka!! it works!! actually I had to remove both the typo and the quotes  for it to work......much appreciated...Thanks

Comment: @MichaelE, nice to hear the problem is solved. these small problems are pin for everyone, and when fixed they serve as stepping stones to becoming a better programmer. but I have a minor problem I haven't experienced before. when the bounty ended, I am given 50 points but at the same time, your acceptance along with its 15 points is removed. any idea?

Comment: I have no idea.... I was using my phone maybe my big fingers touched the acceptance marker at the same time..... I accepted it again 

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to access environment variables contained in a `.env` file. This could be achieved by using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in `src/main.ts`:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

After adding these lines, you can access environment variables like you have put it in your question: `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE`.

Comment: Not just to access .env variables but have them assigned to the Neo4j properties. I am aware of using dotenv and other options but none seems to make the variables available to these properties. I have edited the question to show more clarity.

Comment: Apparently the problem lies somewhere in neo4jmodule's interpretation of the host: <env variable>. If only this variable is hardcoded then everything works fine.....not sure why!

Comment: `HINT The @nestjs/config package internally uses dotenv.`
[nestjs config](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz This I know. The problem doesn't appear to be a config/dotenv problem but one to do the the nest-neo4j wrapper